# auto start using /etc/rc.local or /etc/init.d not working

Tags: boot, raspbian-stretch, pifm, upstart

-My problem:

I can't get autostart to work (/etc/rc.local or /etc/init.d)

/etc/rc.local screen never boots and kills the pi, which then needs to be re-flashed to work again.

/etc/init.d no auto start. Pi is still alive.

/etc/rc.local I can not ssh into the machine to delete the rc.local and holding down shift does not boot into safe mode. so I have to re-flash the .img to try again. and then fail again.

I am following goldilocks help example [pifm Crash Loop my Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61791/pifm-crash-loop-my-raspberry-pi/61812#61812) and code from http://www.icrobotics.co.uk/wiki/index.php/Turning_the_Raspberry_Pi_Into_an_FM_Transmitter#Steps_to_play_sound:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin
(
  exec &>> /var/log/my_rc_local.log
  cd /home/pi/pifm && ./pifm sound.wav 90.5 
) &

exit 0
```

I have tried deleting:
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin

I have also tried different spacing with no luck

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin
(
 exec &>> /var/log/my_rc_local.log
 cd /home/pi/pifm && ./pifm sound.wav 90.5 
)&

exit 0
```

using a /etc/init.d/file.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/pifm
sudo ./pifm sound.wav 90.5
```

then made the script executable using

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/file.sh
```

the test worked!!!

```
sudo /etc/init.d/file.sh start
```

then registered the script

```
sudo update-rc.d file.sh defaults
```

the pi boots/starts but the file.sh is not auto started.

any ideas?

Comment: only thing I can suggest is delaying the execution of `pifm` perhaps put a `sleep 10` in the line before?

Comment: Is there anything in the log file: /var/log/my_rc_local.log

Comment: I can not get to the .log as the pi is killed. no ssh. and no safe mode. no way to see log file.  any ideas John

Comment: I have also tried a /etc/init.d file.  it does not kill the pi but no autostart.

Comment: created the .sh file put it in etc/int.d then made it executable and the test file.sh worked in terminal.  then sudo update-rc.d file.sh defaults to register the script. when I reboot, the pi does not autostart the etc/init.d/file.sh file.

Comment: The answer from Jaromanda X solved the problem.  sleep 10. thank you!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

from Jaromanda X below in comments
add "sleep 10" to the line before

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin
sleep 10
(
  exec &>> /var/log/my_rc_local.log
  cd /home/pi/pifm && ./pifm sound.wav 90.5 
) &

exit 0
```

Comment: please post an answer Jaromanda X so I can give you credit. thanks again!!!